# How to make another nested json with keys from a nested json with C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a json for my api. I was able to create one however I need a  nested json with keys from a nested json

I tried the following codes on C#:

```
public class myModel {
 public string myModelNo {get; set;}
 public List<myName> myName {get;set;}
 public List<myInfo> info {get; set;}
}

public class myName {
 public string firstName{get; set;}
 public string lastName {get; set;}
}

public class myInfo{
 public int index {get; set;}
 public string value {get; set;}
}
```

However, the result is:

```
{
 myModelNo: "ABC1",
 myName: [{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
   }],
 info: [
   {
     index: 1,
     value: "I love apples"
   },
   {
     index: 2,
     value: "My favorite color is red."
   },
   ]
}
```

But this is not the result I needed.

My expected result should be:

```
{
 myModelNo: "ABC1",
 myName: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
 },
 info: [
   {
     index: 1,
     value: "I love apples"
   },
   {
     index: 2,
     value: "My favorite color is red."
   },
   ]
}
```

Note: **myName** is nested and have keys and not an array.

Any help would be great.

Comment: _"myName is nested and have keys and not an array."_ - your C# says it's an array (`List<myName>`)?

Comment: By the way _"I need a nested json with keys from a nested json"_ doesn't make much sense. It makes it sound like you've got some JSON which you need to deserialize into C# objects, and then make that JSON part of a nested object, and then serialize that into a new JSON object. In reality, you simply wanted to serialize a nested C# data structure into JSON.

Comment: Its working as expected

Comment: You need to have `myName` property in `myModel` class as single object. Not as a list

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you are asking (and i am not sure i do). You need to remove your list from the model

```
public List<myName> myName {get;set;}
```

**Example**

```
public class myModel 
{
   public string myModelNo {get; set;}
   public myName myName {get;set;} // Note the removed List
   public List<myInfo> info {get; set;}
}
```